# Cookie+Basic or Cookie+Digest authentication in MVC5 OWIN project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, basic-authentication, owin, digest-authentication, mixed-authentication

I need to support mixed (Cookie+Basic or Cookie+Digest) authentication in ASP.NET MVC5 OWIN project(s).

The goal is to approach easily adding Basic or Digest authentication to **any** Visual Studio project that is using Cookie or other custom authentication (by using our custom wizard).

Mixed authentication (i.e. Cookie+Basic) should work as follows:

1. Try cookie authentication;
2. If the above fails with error 403
   (in our case, if a resource is accessed from MS Office app), instead
   of "403 unauthorized" response issue a Basic authentication.

The above is also called [Mixed Authentication Disposition](https://www.nuget.org/packages/madam), and we have been using a custom HTTP module to achieve this in previous versions of Visual Studio, before MVC5 / OWIN.

The easiest solution that I'm going to implement now is:

1. Create a copy of Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies middleware from
   [Katana project](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) sources;
2. Implement fallback to Basic (or Digest) authentication in AuthenticationHandler implementation.
   For Basic Authentication I'm going to use implementation from [Thinktecture.IdentityModel](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/master/source/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.BasicAuthentication) library.
3. Make the project use new middleware instead of cookies middleware.

Unfortunately, a lot of classes in Microsoft implementation have "internal" access modifier, 
thus I find myself having to copy a lot of code from Microsoft implementation.

Any better suggestions **how to implement fallback from Cookie to Basic or Digest authentication** (I need both implementations) when error 403 is received?

Comment: Have you finished it? In my case for some requests I need additional Digest authentication if no auth cookie is present.